# Change SKU field in email by custom attribute modelnumber

Tags: magento-1.9

I know people already tried to delete the SKU field in the email confirmation field. But I want to something different.

I managed to change the SKU field in "my account" by copying the template as mentioned here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13017942/magento-delete-sku-from-order-email and it worked out great.

Now I was thinking to do the same for the new order confirmation email. I managed to change the column field name and tried to change the default getSku with $_item->getData('mpn'); but it stays empty no matter what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume that `mpn` is a custom product attribute. The reason why nothing shows up when you call `$_item->getData('mpn');` is because that column does not exist in `sales_flat_order_item` table so there is no data to return.

First you need to add `mpn` column to `sales_flat_quote_item` and `sales_flat_order_item` tables. For that you need to create a custom module with setup script.

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->getConnection()
    ->addColumn($installer->getTable('sales/quote_item'), 'mpn', array(
        'type'      => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT,
        'lenght'    => 255,
        'comment'   => 'MPN'
    ));

$installer->getConnection()
    ->addColumn($installer->getTable('sales/order_item'), 'mpn', array(
        'type'      => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT,
        'lenght'    => 255,
        'comment'   => 'MPN'
    ));

$installer->endSetup();
```

Next you need to instruct Magento to copy your custom attribute value to quote item table, and once quote is converted to order, to order item table rows we just created. Add this to your `config.xml` file under `<global>` node.

```
<sales>
    <quote>
        <item>
            <product_attributes>
                <mpn/>
            </product_attributes>
        </item>
    </quote>
</sales>

<fieldsets>
    <sales_convert_quote_item>
        <mpn>
            <to_order_item>*</to_order_item>
        </mpn>
    </sales_convert_quote_item>
</fieldsets>
```

That's it. Now you can call `$_item->getData('mpn');` in your email template. Please note that it will work only for new orders.