# module to add custom code in code_core_mage_sales_etc_config.xml via module or observer

Tags: module, magento-1, event-observer

I want to add order line items in Magento.

I followed  [link](http://www.webcenter.co.in/how-to-add-custom-fields-for-order-line-items-in-magento)

now i have created module for steps in that link

for step 6:

Added in file code_core_mage_sales_etc_config.xml

```
<sales_convert_quote_item>
  <training_location>
    <to_order_item>*</to_order_item>
  </training_location>
</sales_convert_quote_item>
```

**Also Add:**

```
<sales_convert_order_item>
      <training_location>
         <to_quote_item>*</to_quote_item>
         <to_invoice_item>* </to_invoice_item>
         <to_shipment_item>*</to_shipment_item>
         <to_cm_item>*</to_cm_item>
      </training_location>
   </sales_convert_order_item>
```

I do not want to change in code , how can i do above steps via module

pls help

Comment: This should help http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/49557/208

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add this code in the **config.xml** of your module:

```
<config>
    <global>
        <fieldsets>
            <sales_convert_quote_item>
                <training_location>
                    <to_order_item>*</to_order_item>
                </training_location>
            </sales_convert_quote_item>
            <sales_convert_order_item>
                <training_location>
                    <to_quote_item>*</to_quote_item>
                    <to_invoice_item>*</to_invoice_item>
                    <to_shipment_item>*</to_shipment_item>
                    <to_cm_item>*</to_cm_item>
                </training_location>
            </sales_convert_order_item>
        </fieldsets>
    </global>
</config>
```